# trying to overwrite the contents of mongodb via a put request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am following a tutorial and am stack on the last part of it. I am trying to overwrite contents of the database via a 'PUT' request.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const articleSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String
};

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

// Requests Targeting All Routes

app.route("/articles")

.get(function(req, res) {
    Article.find()
        .then((foundArticles) => {
            mongoose.connection.close();
            foundArticles.forEach(function(foundArticle) {
                // console.log(foundArticle);
                res.send(foundArticles);
            })
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
})

.post(function(req, res) {
    const newArticle = new Article({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    });

    newArticle.save()
        .then(function() {
            res.send("Successfully added a new article.");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
})

.delete(function(req, res) {
    Article.deleteMany()
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Successfully deleted the document.");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
});

// Requests Targeting Specific Routes

app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
.get(function(req, res) {
    const title = req.params.articleTitle;
    Article.find({title})
        .then((foundArticle)  => {
            res.send(foundArticle);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
})

// It won't allow the contents of the database to be overwritten.
.put(function(req, res) {
    Article.replaceOne({ title: req.params.articleTitle },
        {
          title: req.body.title,
          content: req.body.content,
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Successfully updated article.");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
})
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000!");
});
```

The contents of the database are in this format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6517a22854d8425f4e613d9e"),
    "title" : "REST",
    "content" : "REST is short for REpresentational State Transfer. It's an architectural style for designing APIs."
}
```

I am trying this in Postman and there is no error. But the problem is that the contents of the database isn't updated. Since there is no error that is shown, it is hard to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You should use the `updateOne` API to update a document.

```js
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
.put((req, res) => {
  const title = req.params.articleTitle;
  Article.updateOne({
    title
  }, {
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
  })
  .then(() => {
    res.send("Successfully updated article.");
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
})
```

### refs

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.updateOne()